# How Can I Reorder/Sort The Collections List in Directus?

Tags: interface, headless, directus

The collections in the current version of Directus - version 7 - are displayed in the 'Collections' sidebar, in the order in which they are created. That often doesn't make sense. As the data evolves, we may create collections which we may want to list *NOT* in the bottom of the list.

Is there a way to sort or reorder the collections list in Directus?

Answer (score 2):

> in the order in which they are created

They're ordered alphabetically (at least on load), which is arguably not the most useful either..

As of right now, there is no way to order or group them manually.

However, there is an open discussion on potential ways to make the sidebar navigation customizable: https://github.com/directus/app/issues/125